# Disappear horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with my layout. It seems like a horizontal scroll appears on the screen and I don't want that. I already tried to find the problem but I can't see it.
You can see the whole code in codepen.
[click to open codepen](https://codepen.io/LucasFer/full/jBeYPj/)

```
.header{
   background:rgb(230, 94, 94);
   width:8vw;
   height:100%;
   position: fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
 }
```

Maybe the problem is the above code, but I recommend you that enter to codepen link to see all CSS and html.
You should change the view to editor view.
I hope somebody can find the problem because I can't see it,  by the wa, I'm new in HTML & CSS that means maybe it's a fool problem.
Thanks and good luck!

Comment: I don't see a horizontal scroll. What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce that viewport width set on your div `main-content` a little you might get what you want.
example set width to `99vw;`

```
.main-content{
    width:100vw;
    background:white;
    padding-left:8vw;
  width:99vw;
}
```

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/WpadMN)

Comment: It doesn't work like I was waiting because I see on the right the body's color and I don't want that.But in the other hand is a quickly solution.

Comment: no biggy just set width to 99.3vw just 0.3vw extra. I believe the padding set in vw and other mesaurement set if vw is causing some overflow and making the div scrollable